# list all shortcuts of a QMainWindow

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard-shortcuts, pyside2

I have a PySide2 application that is growing in size, and I'd like to dump all shortcuts.
Is there a simple solution?

The first objective is to be able to list them (let's say to check they are all documented and there's no duplicates), but I'll very soon be interested in letting the user customize them (so if someone has an example of a shortcut editor, I'll be interested too; I only found this https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq14-actioneditor.html for the moment).

This post [Qt - Disable/enable all shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50887393/qt-disable-enable-all-shortcuts) suggests `findChildren`, so I've come up with a beginning of a solution (see code below), but I'm feeling there could be something included natively in Qt that I may have missed?

```
# This is file mygui.py
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QAction, QMessageBox, QMainWindow, QApplication
from PySide2.QtGui import QIcon, QKeySequence


class MyGUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('My GUI')
        self.fileMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu('&File')
        self.toolBar = self.addToolBar('my toolbar')

        act = QAction('About', self)
        act.triggered.connect(self.popup_hello)
        act.setShortcuts(['Ctrl+A'])
        for x in [self.fileMenu, self.toolBar]: x.addAction(act)

        act = QAction('Show shortcuts', self)
        act.triggered.connect(self.display_shortcuts)
        for x in [self.fileMenu, self.toolBar]: x.addAction(act)

        act = QAction('Quit', self, icon=QIcon.fromTheme('exit'))
        act.setShortcuts(QKeySequence.Quit)
        act.triggered.connect(self.close)
        for x in [self.fileMenu, self.toolBar]: x.addAction(act)


    def popup_hello(self):
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Bienvenue')
        QMessageBox.about(self, 'About', 'This is my GUI. v0.1')


    def display_shortcuts(self):
        for action in self.findChildren(QAction) :
            print(type(action), action.toolTip(), [x.toString() for x in action.shortcuts()])



if __name__ == '__main__':
    qt_app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = MyGUI()
    app.show()
    #app.dumpObjectTree()
    app.display_shortcuts()
    qt_app.exec_()
```

This displays:

```
$ python3 mygui.py
<class 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QAction'> File []
<class 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QAction'> my toolbar []
<class 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QAction'> About ['Ctrl+A']
<class 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QAction'> Show shortcuts []
<class 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QAction'> Quit ['Ctrl+Q']
```

One bonus questions:

- I don't see why 'my toolbar' is listed here as a QAction?

[edit] since there doesn't seem to be a native solution, I've started a small widget [here](https://github.com/Demi-Lune/snippets/blob/master/QShortcutEditor.py).

Comment: What output do you expect to get?

Comment: The output is correct (except maybe for 'my toolbar'). I'm just surprised by this solution using `findChildren`.  I'd expect all shortcuts to be maybe registered somewhere.  Or have a standard Qt function for this job.

Comment: Maybe for your editor it helps to use [QKeySequenceEdit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequenceedit.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is there a simple solution?**

There is no native method to find all the shortcuts in a window so your methodology is correct.

**I don't see why 'my toolbar' is listed here as a QAction?**

Not every QAction implies having an associated QShortcut, in the case of QToolBar it already has a default QAction which is the [toggleViewAction()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html#toggleViewAction), that is the one you are getting and that does not have an associated shortcut.